# How to separate between own and external packages in checkstyle?

Tags: java, eclipse, checkstyle

I have the following Java import statements:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.eclipse.core.runtime.jobs.Job;
import org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI;

import com.iauko.commons.Resources;
```

The package "com.iauko.commons.Resources" is my local package, part of the Java project, while all other imports are external packages. I would like to organize the imports so that the external packages appear first, followed by my own package. The checkstyle warns me with  the following warning:

> Wrong lexicographical order for `'com.iauko.commons.Resources'` import. Should be before `'org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI'`".

Is there a way to modify the checkstyle file so that I will have the "external packages" first and the my own packages? Maybe somehow by using the fact the all my own packages are starting with `"com.iauko"`?

Comment: I don't think so. But you could rename your package so it comes last lexically. `zzz.iauko` is legal, valid and perfectly acceptable.

Comment: You can find all options to control the import rule in the docs: https://checkstyle.org/config_imports.html

I never used it, but it may help you to reach your goal. But I would go with the standard setting because most IDEs come with that. If you want others to join your project, project-specific non-standard formatting rules are never a good choice.